# jQuery - disable selects which follow after

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to create a number of dropdown menus which values depend on the previous selection.
What I'm trying to achieve is to get all following selects become disabled if the preceding one hasn't got the value selected.

Say someone has picked an option from the first one, second one and third one - then have selected a blank value from the first one - I would like all following ones - regardless of how many there are - become disabled again.

I've collected all selects in the form:

```
var sels = obj.closest('form').find('input[type="select"]');
```

I think that perhaps I should get the index of the selected one and then disable all other indexes, but don't quite know how to do it.

Here's the structure of the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">  

<select name="option-1" id="option-1">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>


<select name="option-2" id="option-2">
    <option value="">----</option>
</select>

<select name="option-3" id="option-3" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">----</option>
</select>   

</form>
```

Now - I know how to enable them - I just need to find out how to disable all relevant ones when the user changes one of the menu values to blank.

Comment: i doubt .find('input[type="select"]') will give you selects, selects are not 'input' elements.  you should use .find('select'); instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great function in jQuery called: `nextAll()`;

When you write event handler to select fields like below you can jump to all next selects with this function and disable them.

```
$("select").change(function(){
  $("select").removeAttr("disabled");
  if($(this).val()==0){
    $(this).nextAll().attr("disabled","disabled");
  }
});
```

You just need to specify properly which `select`s you want to affect.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">-Choose-</option>
    <option value="1">Valid option</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="0">-Choose-</option>
    <option value="1">Valid option</option>
</select>
<!-- As many selects as you like -->
```

The following jQuery should work:

```
var sels = $("select");
sels.not(":first").prop("disabled", true);
sels.change(function() {
    if($(this).val() !== "0") {
        $(this).next().prop("disabled", false);   
    }
    else {
        $(this).nextAll("select").val("0").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vv9UP/4/). It simply disables all but the first `select`, binds a `change` event to all of them, and in the event handler it checks to see if a valid value has been selected. If so, it enables the next `select`. If not, it disables it. Note that [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) requires jQuery version at least 1.6. If you have to use an older version, you can safely use `.attr` instead.

Comment: Thanks James - that's not quite right as when you select all of them and then change the first menu to blank - only the second one goes disabled - and the other ones stay unchanged.

Comment: Ahh, very true. You should be able to easily modify it to do that. Just disable all subsequent `select` elements instead of `nextSel` in the `else` block.

Comment: @user398341 - I've updated the code and the fiddle, so try it now.

Comment: Thanks James - avall has already suggested the nextAll() and it works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few elements of this, first off, you can find out what the index of the currently changed select is by using the `.index`<sup>[docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/)</sup> method.

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   // find the index of the changed selects within all selects
   var index = $('select').index($this); 
})
```

Secondly, you can disable all following selects using the `gt()`<sup>[docs](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)</sup> selector.

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
   var index = $('select').index($this);
   $('select:gt(' + index + ')').attr('disabled',$this.val() == '');

});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mQmfb/

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the jquery plugins that would already deal with your issue. See this [jquery plugin page](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/multiple-select) for some examples.

Yet, if you want to enable selects when the previous one is selected, you'd probably better:

1. **disable all your selects** at first.
2. **enable the first one** when the page loads (or within your code, depending on how your HTML is created)
3. enable the **following** select with a [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and the right selector (depending on your HTML code (hence you haven't posted it, we cannot help you more)

Comment: Sorry - just added the form structure to my post.

Comment: @user398341: thanks. Actually, James' answer is very clear and should fit your needs :)